# eclipse disable auto copy when selecting text

Tags: eclipse

working with eclipse (dvt addon - e programing language)

I want to disable auto coping when selecting text.
I want the regular CTRL+C CTRL+V to work.

thank

Eran

I tried to look for copy / select in the eclipse preferences.

Comment: It doesn't do that out of the box, except sometimes on Linux when the native controls employ the X11 selection buffer. Which environment are you on, and could this be the work of another plug-in you have installed? Does it happen everywhere?